# Error fórmula SECUENCIA en EXCEL si le pasas como argumento ALEATORIO.ENTRE

Tags: excel

Me ha surgido la necesidad de generar un listado de meses de manera aleatoria. La única restricción es mantener un orden lógico, de manera que enero sea el primer mes y diciembre el último, pero pueden repetirse entre 1 y 5 veces todos los meses.

La fórmula que utilizo es esta. Nada del otro mundo:

```
=REDUCE(
"enero";
SECUENCIA(12);
LAMBDA(acu; cur;
    APILARV(
        acu;
        MAP(
            SECUENCIA(SI.ERROR(ALEATORIO.ENTRE(1; 5); 2));
            LAMBDA(n; TEXTO("1/" & cur; "mmmm"))
        )
    )
)
  )
```

El problema que tengo es que la fórmula SECUENCIA devuelve, no siempre, error de desbordamiento si se le pasa como argumento una fórmula que genere un número aleatorio. He probado varias alternativas sin éxito. ¿A alguien se le ha presentado el mismo problema y lo ha resuelto de algún modo en concreto? Agradecería ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de darle muchas vueltas, para evitar la solución más fácil (usar Código VBA) la solución que he encontrado es que el numero aleatorio que calculas no sea volátil. ALEATORIO.ENTRE es volátil y como Excel da varias pasadas de cálculo interno en la formula, en algunos casos el numero aleatorio, desde que empieza el cálculo de la formula completa hasta que acaba, cambia, por lo que da error.
La solución que he encontrado es que dicho número aleatorio se calcule en base al segundo del "TIME" y de esa manera, cada segundo dará un aleatorio entre 1 y 5 distinto sin dar error.

Por lo que quedaría así:

```
=REDUCE(
"enero";SECUENCIA(12);LAMBDA(acu;cur;APILARV(
        acu;MAP(
            SECUENCIA(REDONDEAR(RESIDUO(SEGUNDO(AHORA())*4;5)+1;0));LAMBDA(n; TEXTO("1/" & cur; "mmmm")))
    )
)
  )
```

Comment: Muy buena opción amigo. Gracias.